# How to access free hand signature added by user to PDF using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a PDF document that is signed by user as described here (scroll to "Sign or Initial your form" section): https://helpx.adobe.com/reader/using/fill-and-sign.html

This PDF has Javascript attached that submits form data contained in the PDF to an URL. I would like to submit the user signature image but I don't know how to access it. I have tried "this.getAnnots()" and "this.dataObjects" but they are both empty. I see no other places I could look for the data. The PDF Javascript API is described here: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not through the Acrobat JS API. The image data for that type of signature is stored in a dictionary specific to Adobe Sign and there is no public JS API to it.

Comment: Can I access a drawing made by user with a "Draw free form" tool (the pen icon)? I just need a simple signature (not with certificate)