# PHP Adobe Signature PDF Hand writing with mouse or stylus

Tags: php, adobe, digital-signature, adobe-sign

I am trying to integrate Adobe Signature in PDF where end user can sign it on browser itself, I want his/her hand written signature on it. End user will use his/her mouse  to draw the signature. This PDF creation is written in PHP and application contains Adobe APIs.

I referred to the [Handwritten Adobe page](https://www.adobe.com/sign/esignature-resources/handwritten-signature.html) and  [Adobe tags](https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/using/text-tag.html)
I have also referred to [Stack 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301230/how-to-access-free-hand-signature-added-by-user-to-pdf-using-javascript) and [stack 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788863/customizing-signature-fields-in-document-using-adobe-sign-api), not matching to my requirement.
I was able to sign the custom runtime generated PDF document using *{{Sig_es_:signer1:signature}}*

I checked it at several places including Stackoverflow, but i cant find any such reference document which can guide me to code for hand written signatures. i also need to understand if Hand written signatures have any limitation or drawbacks or any privacy/security issues.
Let me know if anyone knows How to proceed on this.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a signature with a mouse? That will not work. I can't do that. A finger on a phone would work better. Still clumsy, but better.

Drawn signatures are old fashioned in the digital world, and require complex verifiable encryption. You would have to prove that the digital copy you have, was indeed drawn within the exact document it appears in. Digital things can, after all, be copied easily. Whenever there's a dispute you would have to prove that the signature is an inherent part of the unchangeable digital document. This is far more difficult than it seems at first. That's why it is usually quite expensive.

I would strongly advice to not go down this road. Find another solution.

You haven't explained what you want to use the signature for, which makes it difficult for me to suggest another solution, so I won't.

Comment: i am looking for screenshots shown in adobe link given in the post.  https://www.adobe.com/sign/esignature-resources/handwritten-signature.html

Comment: @MangeshSathe Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. Do you want to tell me something?

Comment: we are creating a contract PDF using PHP, we want end user to sign it on browser itself without installing full Adobe. so we need to know how can we show signature box in PDF. "{{Sig_es_:signer1:signature}}" is working fine for us but we need signature box

Comment: @MangeshSathe Thank you for the clarification, but I think I already got that from your question. My answer, as well as the one from Larry K, is meant to discourage you from trying to do this. You can buy an existing solution, but doing this **correctly** yourself in PHP is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> i also need to understand if Hand written signatures have any limitation or drawbacks or any privacy/security issues.

Yes, there are lots of limitations and drawbacks. You need to consider the issues of forgery (someone else signing as me, Larry) and non-reputability (I signed it but later claim that it wasn't me. How do you prove that it was Larry who signed it?)

There's also the overall context of the signature: what is the value of the agreement? What are the consequences of not being able to prove that the right person did sign the document?

Adobe Sign (and their competitors) have answers to all of the above. eSignatures are far more complicated than just getting something that looks like the person's signature on the PDF.

Pro-tip: how the signature looks on the PDF is the least important part of the process.